# Pass Vector by reference and Get Error

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Following code is for test the pass the reference of a vector to a function. However, it will have some unknown fault. I got the error message from gdb as following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wkCu.jpg]

Source is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class ROLE
{
    public:
        ROLE(int);
        int HP;
};
ROLE::ROLE (int input)
{
    HP = input;
}

void checkVector(vector<ROLE>&input);
int main()
{
vector<ROLE> R;
    ROLE K(102);
    R.push_back(K);
    K.HP = 111;
    R.push_back(K);
    checkVector(R);

    return 1;
}
void checkVector(vector <ROLE> & input)
{
    cout<<"size of vector "<<input.size()<<endl;
    for(int i =0; i<input.size();i++)
    {
        cout<< input[i].HP<<endl;
    }
}
```

I can't find the reason of the error. Any idea is appreciated!

I realized that error probably from the push_back, because I also get the error if I modified the code as following. Are there any idea about what happened?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class ROLE
{
    public:
        ROLE(int);
        int HP;
};
ROLE::ROLE (int input)
{
    HP = input;
}
int main()
{
    vector<ROLE> R;
    ROLE K(0);
    K.HP=1;
    R.push_back(K);
    K.HP = 113;
    R.push_back(K);
    K.HP = 111;
    R.push_back(K);


    return 0;
}
```

Possible answer:

I get one way which can avoid the error. 
Following is the no-error source.

```
#include<iostream>   
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class ROLE
{
    public:
        ROLE(int);
        void constructAry(int inputHP);
        int HP;
};  
ROLE::ROLE (int input)
{
    HP = input;
}
void ROLE::constructAry(int inputHP)
{
    HP = inputHP;
}
void checkVector(vector<ROLE>&input);
int main()
{
    vector<int> test;
    vector<ROLE> R;
    ROLE K(0);
    K.constructAry(1);
    R.push_back(K);
    K.constructAry(2);
    R.push_back(K);
    K.constructAry(3);
    R.push_back(K);
    K.constructAry(4);
    R.push_back(K);
    checkVector(R);
    return 1;
}

void checkVector(vector <ROLE> & input)
{
    cout<<"size of vector "<<input.size()<<endl;
    for(int i =0; i<input.size();i++)
    {
        cout<< input[i].HP<<endl;
    }
}
```

So it seems that using a constructor-like function to modify the value of the same object and push_back the object in the vector can effectively avoid the bug.

The reason is ambiguous for me. Maybe the memory address's matter.

Comment: I can't see any mistake in the posted code (http://ideone.com/oCQ8L).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the program as posted in your question.

Comment: Yep, same here, nothing wrong with the code. I would change `return 1;` to `return 0;` in `main`. Generally non-zero return values from `main` are used to indicate an error.

Comment: I really hope you've posted the exact code you are having a problem with. Because if so this is a well asked question.

Comment: Is it possible you are using an incompatible version of gdb with your gcc? If you invoke the compiler as "gcc", do a "gcc -v" to show its version. Also, do "gdb -v" to show the gdb version.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. I ran the code in Visual studio with no problems. However, when I ran it with gcc it did cause an error, look at http://ideone.com/q8brJ.

Comment: @DigitalDa: ideone reports an error because `main` returns 1. If you return 0, the error goes away.

Comment: Why do you think it's an error? gdb just tells you it stopped running your program because it reached a breakpoint you set. That's normal. Just type next or step.

Comment: Thanks all the responses! However, the error,"program no response" is still exist, even though I changed the return value. My gcc version is 4.5.2 from Mingw. and My system is x86.